# Responsive ChartJS in Bootstrap Table Cell

Tags: bootstrap-4, chart.js

I am struggling with adding multiple pie charts of ChartJS into a bootstrap table cell. I am not sure what else I can do to make the current code works as the expected result. Appreciate all your helps and please let me know if I need to clarify anything more.
Here is my work progress so far:
[image]

And here is the expected result:
[image]

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
<td class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 4em;">
         <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 4em;">
         <canvas id="chart2"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 4em;">
         <canvas id="chart3"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 4em;">
         <canvas id="chart4"></canvas>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="">
    <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 4em;">
         <canvas id="chart5"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 4em;">
         <canvas id="chart6"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 4em;">
         <canvas id="chart7"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 4em;">
         <canvas id="chart8"></canvas>
    </div>
 </td>
```

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            responsive: true,
            cutoutPercentage: 80,
        }
    });
```

Comment: where is the JS part?

Comment: I'm sorry. Let me add the JS chart part. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple implementation for creating chart using loops.
you may need to adjust color and data to get the desired result as you want in your *expected result*.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName('chart-container');
for (let i = 0; i < ctx.length; i++) {
  let chartref = ctx[i].getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');

  let myChart = new Chart(chartref, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ['Blue', 'Grey'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [10, 12, Math.random() * 4],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.3)'
        ],
      }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      responsive: true,
      cutoutPercentage: 80,
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<td class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
  <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 8em;">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 8em;">
    <canvas id="chart2"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 8em;">
    <canvas id="chart3"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 8em;">
    <canvas id="chart4"></canvas>
  </div>
</td>
<td class="">
  <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 8em;">
    <canvas id="chart5"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 8em;">
    <canvas id="chart6"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 8em;">
    <canvas id="chart7"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="chart-container flex-fill" style="position: relative; width: 8em;">
    <canvas id="chart8"></canvas>
  </div>
</td>
```